# replace single space but not multiple space python

Tags: python, regex

I believe this can be done with regex bux cant seem to find the correct syntax.

```
'SYS           W$_FIasdfLESTATXS               TABLE PARTITION           0    '
```

The third field in my file sometimes has space seperated output that needs to be converted to underscore seperated output so the above would become this.

```
'SYS           W$_FIasdfLESTATXS               TABLE_PARTITION           0    '
```

The third field is not always the same but when space seperated it will always have a single space.  How can this be accomplished in python?

Comment: You may want to play with toy like http://rubular.com/ to practice your regexp skills. PS answer to your question is on that website in the tooltip ;)

Comment: see to check your syntax http://www.regexr.com

Comment: so if you do (\S \S) you can get 'E P' but i'm not sure how to reference that to replace it with E_P in this case.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the REGEX you want : `s/([^ ]) ([^ ])/\1_\2/g`

In Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> my_string='SYS           W$_FIasdfLESTATXS               TABLE PARTITION           0    '
>>> re.sub(r'([^ ]) ([^ ])',r'\1_\2',my_string)
'SYS           W$_FIasdfLESTATXS               TABLE_PARTITION           0    '
```

Comment: Awesome, didnt know how to backreference like that, This one also works   re.sub(r'(\S) (\S)',r'\1_\2',x)

Comment: Your regex is better expressed as `s/(\S)\s(\S)/\1_\2/g`

Answer (score 1):

Use a lookbehind and lookahead:

```
(?<=\w) (?=\w)
```

Or

```
(?<=\S)\s(?=\S)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zW2aW9/2)

In Python:

```
>>> s='SYS           W$_FIasdfLESTATXS               TABLE PARTITION           0    '
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\S)\s(?=\S)', '_', s)
'SYS           W$_FIasdfLESTATXS               TABLE_PARTITION           0    '
```

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern

```
(?<! ) (?! )
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/248)

```
(?<!            # Negative Look-Behind
                # " " a white space
)               # End of Negative Look-Behind
                # " " a white space
(?!             # Negative Look-Ahead
                # " " a white space
)               # End of Negative Look-Ahead
```