# Python: substitute double space with one space and remove single space

Tags: python, string

I would like to change a string like this:

```
T h i s  i s  a  t e s t
```

to:

```
This is a test
```

This is my code, that works

```
    while '  ' in s:
      s = s.replace('  ', '$$')        
    while ' ' in s:
      s = s.replace(' ', '')
    while '$$' in s:
      s = s.replace('$$', ' ')
```

But, are there simple solutions for this?

There are similar solutions for removing all spaces or removing single spaces and keeping multiple spaces, but in my case, I must substitute double spaces with single space too.

Comment: How do you know which spaces to include and which ones to exclude? The string could be **anything**!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replace single space but not multiple space python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923941/replace-single-space-but-not-multiple-space-python)

Comment: `while` loop in your example code is not necessary, because `str.replace` without the third argument will replace **all** specified (first argument) substrings in a string with the second argument-string. So you can do the same thing in just one line: `s = s.replace('  ', '$$').replace(' ', '').replace('$$', ' ')`. It's a pretty simple solution itself, though you shouldn't foget that it will *fail* if there are another $ chars in the string.

Answer (score 5):

```
s="T h i s  i s  a  t e s t"

s=" ".join([str(i).replace(" ","") for i in s.split("  ")])
```

This should work.

Explanation:

1. Create a new list by splitting the string (s) when 2 spaces are encountered.
2. Create a new list by iterating over the previously constructed list and replacing spaces in each item.
3. Create a new string by joining the previously created list separating each element with a space.

Answer (score 4):

[A little amendment to this and poof!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923941/replace-single-space-but-not-multiple-space-python):

```
import re

s = 'T h i s  i s  a  t e s t'
print(re.sub(r'([^ ]) ([^ ])',r'\1 \2',s))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
This is a test
```

Comment: It doesn't remove single spaces!

Comment: @Ahmad  off from my desk now, will add a fix with different cases tomorrow, cheers

Answer (score 2):

You could use a negative lookahead in re:

```
import re

s = 'T h i s  a  t e s t'
t = re.sub(r' (?! )', '', s)
print(t)
```

gives as expected

```
This is a test
```

---

In fact it removes one space for every sequence of spaces:

```
>>> t= 'T h i s  i s   a    t e s t'
>>> re.sub(r' (?! )', '', t)
'This is  a   test'
```

Comment: Good, but it keeps double spaces

Comment: @Ahmad It should remove one space from every sequence of spaces.

Comment: It should remove every space after a letter

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'T h i s   i s   a   t e s t'
''.join([row[0] for row in zip(s, range(len(s)+1)) if row[1]%2==0])
```

Results:

```
'This is a test'
```